# MemoryCacheImageOutputStream To BufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have some image constrain code that allows you to output to a MemoryCacheImageOutputStream, but I need to get this back into a BufferedImage, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

As `MemoryCacheImageOutputStream` implements `ImageInputStream`, you could just use it as an input stream for an `ImageReader`. So you would end up with something like this (very basic, not tested):

```
public BufferedImage readImage(MemoryCacheImageOutputStream input) {       
    ImageInputStream is = input;
    ImageReader decoder = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("JPEG").next();
    decoder.setInput(is);
    BufferedImage bi = decoder.read(0);
    return bi;
}
```